# What does "scrap" mean in "“father had taught them to do: drive semis, weld, scrap.” - book “Educated” by Tara Westover?

Tags: word-meaning

In the book “Educated” by Tara Westover, chapter 5, what does *scrap* mean in the following?

> Tony and Shawn had left the mountain, but they’d left to do what my father had taught them to do: drive semis, weld, scrap.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It most likely refers to working with scrap metal. This could include collecting scrap metal, collecting items (like cars) to make into scrap metal, or disposing of scrap metal. The aim is usually to make money.

Comment: "The Westover family lived on a farm in rural Idaho, where [their father] Gene made a living salvaging scrap metal..." – [sparknotes.com](https://www.sparknotes.com/lit/educated/summary/) - The aim is to *always* make money. A 55gal drum of 2" copper pipe got me $600. After that I was hooked.

Comment: I have never heard the word "scrap" used as a verb in this context.

Comment: *scrap*, verb: discard or remove from service (a retired, old, or inoperative vehicle, vessel, or machine), especially so as to convert it to scrap metal. *"the decision was made to scrap the entire fleet"*

Comment: I know this is the accepted answer but I really believe it means 'fight'. Being that driving a  semi is 'tough' and you can get mugged/robbed. Knowing how to fight dirty...

Comment: @J.Hirsch from the book: "My oldest brother, Tony, drove rigs, hauling gravel or scrap, trying to scrape together enough money to marry the girl down the road. Shawn, the next oldest, had quarreled with Dad a few months before and taken off. I hadn’t seen him since, though Mother got a hurried call every few weeks telling her he was fine, that he was welding or driving rigs. If Tyler left too, Dad wouldn’t have a crew, and without a crew he couldn’t build barns or hay sheds. He would have to fall back on scrapping."

Comment: Welp, there ya go @legatrix. THAT is the definitive quote that drives the definition of the aforementioned term.

Answer (score 13):

"scrap" can also mean "fight" or "argue", usually implying a not too serious conflict. This **might** mean that the father had taught Tony and Shawn to drive semis, weld, and fight. This is a little more plausible because "scrap" as a verb meaning ."discard" is transitive, and should specify what is being scrapped, and if the meaning is "work with scrap metal" then "scrap" is not a normal verb to use, it is normally a noun or an adjective in that context.

However, the tone seems informal so one cannot be sure that non-standared usage will not be present. Without more context, one can only guess.

Comment: Out of context, that would be a plausible guess. In context, it is almost certainly something that fits in the same category as truck driving and welding. Scrapping motor vehicles fits the description.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - Collecting and selling scrap metal in general, yeah, not just cars. Washers, dryers, old gates, wheelbarrows, ...

Comment: Given the added context now linked in another answer, this is almost surely incorrect, and "scrap" is being used to mean "the process of finding and selling scrap metal". That is a non-0standard verbing of a noun, but English does that. I am going to leave the answer up because it shows the way plausible  reasoning without context can work, and because the alternate4 meanign of "scrap" as "fight" should be known to larners.

Comment: Wish I still had a scrapper in my neighborhood. Not so much for the fisticuffs (he was a wild drunk), but now I need to figure out what to do with this old water heater.

Comment: @Z4-tier In my area the county runs a recycling center that accepts such things, and will schedule curbside pickups on request. If a contractor installs a new water heater, s/he is required to remove the old one and deliver it to the recycling center. This is probably not the case everywhere.

Comment: In Chicago, you're lucky if it's still in the alley half an hour later. - This is correct, but wrong. Without *drive semis* and *weld*, your father having taught you how to *scrap*... that would be how to fight, +1... (except it's prefaced by *do*... *do scrap*, and it's not using the verb, it's the noun: "discarded metal for reprocessing"... 'their father taught them how to do discarded metal for reprocessing'.)

Comment: @Mazura - that translation doesn't work too well. 'Do scrap' is o.k., but 'do drive semis, do weld'?

Comment: @Mazura In the quoted text, "drive" is a verb, and so is "weld", and therefore "scap" should be used as a verb here also.Consider the following parallel example: "There are three sorts of things that people do: work, eat, and sleep".  "Things that people do" introduces a list of verbs, and so it is in the quote.

Comment: Agreed- in this context, it means 'fight'. Fisticuffs ought to have been used too elsewhere in the text.